# FOR XML PATH in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Hi everyone I'm trying convert this code so it works in postgres. I figured I will use to_char(dateinquar:: date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') instead of convert(varchar,dateinquar,101). But I'm not sure what can be used instead of FOR XML PATH? I don't need to generate any XML document. How would I get multiple dates in a single row separated by comma for the case below?

```
Case d.Closing  WHEN 0 THEN  NULL  WHEN 1 THEN ( 
        substring((SELECT convert(varchar,dateinquar,101) + ', ' FROM PDT_tblAReasons sub  
                   WHERE sub.IDnumber = d.IDnumber and dateoutquar IS NULL 
                   GROUP BY IDnumber,dateinquar FOR XML PATH('')),0,len(( 
                   SELECT convert(varchar,dateinquar,101) + ', ' FROM PDT_tblAReasons sub 
                   WHERE sub.IDnumber = d.IDnumber and dateoutquar IS NULL 
                   GROUP BY IDnumber,dateinquar FOR XML PATH('')))-0)) end As [Closing Date]
```

Thank you

Comment: Please explain what this code does. Ideally by adding some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. (please [edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: In general, to aggregate multiple strings into one, `string_agg()` is used in Postgres. If you want to generate XML documents there are [various functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-PRODUCING-XML) to do that.

Comment: You used two tags: sql-server and postgresql. Please remove not needs tags. Otherwise, it is very confusing.